# Number of occurrence of specific value in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I am fetching data from mongodb and
I am getting following array as output from mongodb.
Now i tried many PHP script to  get count of devicetype but not get expected result

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array(
                [_id] => 5774c1c17ffbe048da119681
                [config] => Array(
                        [MOD001] => Array(
                                [devicetype] => modbus
                                [modbusManufacturer] => amit
                                [register_0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value0] => UPS Power
                                        [location0] => 2
                                    )

                                [register_1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value1] => Mains Power
                                        [location1] => 2

                                    )
                            )
                        [MOD002] => Array(
                                [devicetype] => modbus
                                [modbusManufacturer] => konsultera
                                [register_0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value0] => Lobby Temp
                                        [location0] => 22
                                    )

                                [register_1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value1] => Mains Power
                                        [location1] => 2
                                    )
                            )
                        [NBA001|NBR001|NBE001] => Array
                            (
                                [devicetype] => sensor
                                [zoneNo] => 2                            
                            )
                        [NBA002|NBR002|NBE002] => Array
                            (
                                [devicetype] => sensor
                                [zoneNo] => a                            
                            )
                        [RM001] => Array
                            (
                                [devicetype] => relay    
                                [nodeId] => 001                            
                            )
                        [RM002] => Array
                            (
                                [devicetype] => relay  
                                [nodeId] => 001     
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Now I need count of devicetype like below
modbus 2
relay 2
sensor 2

Answer (score 0):

I haven't properly tested this anyway try,

```
function multi_array_search($array, $search)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $sub = multi_array_search($value, $search);
                if (count($sub)) {
                    return $array_occur_count;
                }  
            } 
        }
    }
```